# Detect availability of <Secure/SecRandom.h>?

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, c-preprocessor, macports

I'm working with a cross-platform C++ library. While the library attempts to be agnostic, it does integrate with frameworks like Cocoa/CocoaTouch Security framework on occasion.

On modern Darwin systems, like OS X 107, 10.8 and 10.9 (and iOS equivalents), the following works as expected. The modern systems use Xcode 4.3 and above.

```
#include <Secure/SecRandom.h>
```

On an older PowerMac running OS X 10.5 with Xcode 3.1, the include causes a [compile error](https://github.com/randombit/botan/issues/799#issuecomment-270135233). The older PowerMac is still alive for testing because its a big-endian, PowerPC cpu.

```
$ make
...
/opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-3.4  -m64 -pthread -stdlib=libc++ -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden
-std=c++11 -D_REENTRANT -fstack-protector -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Ibuild/include
-c ./src/lib/entropy/darwin_secrandom/darwin_secrandom.cpp -o build/obj/lib/entropy_darwin_secrandom.o

./src/lib/entropy/darwin_secrandom/darwin_secrandom.cpp:10:10: fatal error: 
      'Security/SecRandom.h' file not found
#include <Security/SecRandom.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [build/obj/lib/entropy_darwin_secrandom.o] Error 1
```

My question is, how can we tell when `<Security/SecRandom.h>` is available? Is it tied to Xcode 4 and above? Or is it tied to something else? If so, what preprocessor macro do we use to detect the availability?

---

When I look at the preprocessor macros, I don't see what is used to signal users. Obviously, the MacPorts compiler is integrating with (or aware of) frameworks like Cocoa and CocoaTouch because we can include headers like `TargetConditionals.h`:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-3.4 -m64 -pthread -stdlib=libc++ -fPIC -include TargetConditionals.h -x c++ -dM -E - < /dev/null | sort
#define OBJC_NEW_PROPERTIES 1
#define TARGET_CPU_68K 0
#define TARGET_CPU_ALPHA 0
#define TARGET_CPU_MIPS 0
#define TARGET_CPU_PPC 1
#define TARGET_CPU_PPC64 0
#define TARGET_CPU_SPARC 0
#define TARGET_CPU_X86 0
#define TARGET_CPU_X86_64 0
#define TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED 0
#define TARGET_OS_MAC 1
#define TARGET_OS_UNIX 0
#define TARGET_OS_WIN32 0
#define TARGET_RT_64_BIT 0
#define TARGET_RT_BIG_ENDIAN 1
#define TARGET_RT_LITTLE_ENDIAN 0
#define TARGET_RT_MAC_CFM 0
#define TARGET_RT_MAC_MACHO 1
#define _ARCH_PPC 1
#define _ARCH_PPC64 1
#define _BIG_ENDIAN 1
#define _LP64 1
#define _REENTRANT 1
#define __APPLE_CC__ 6000
#define __APPLE__ 1
#define __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE 2
#define __ATOMIC_ACQ_REL 4
#define __ATOMIC_CONSUME 1
#define __ATOMIC_RELAXED 0
#define __ATOMIC_RELEASE 3
#define __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST 5
#define __BIG_ENDIAN__ 1
#define __BYTE_ORDER__ __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__
#define __CHAR16_TYPE__ unsigned short
#define __CHAR32_TYPE__ unsigned int
#define __CHAR_BIT__ 8
#define __CONSTANT_CFSTRINGS__ 1
#define __DBL_DENORM_MIN__ 4.9406564584124654e-324
#define __DBL_DIG__ 15
#define __DBL_EPSILON__ 2.2204460492503131e-16
#define __DBL_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __DBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __DBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __DBL_MANT_DIG__ 53
#define __DBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 308
#define __DBL_MAX_EXP__ 1024
#define __DBL_MAX__ 1.7976931348623157e+308
#define __DBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-307)
#define __DBL_MIN_EXP__ (-1021)
#define __DBL_MIN__ 2.2250738585072014e-308
#define __DECIMAL_DIG__ 33
#define __DEPRECATED 1
#define __DYNAMIC__ 1
#define __ENVIRONMENT_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED__ 1050
#define __EXCEPTIONS 1
#define __FINITE_MATH_ONLY__ 0
#define __FLT_DENORM_MIN__ 1.40129846e-45F
#define __FLT_DIG__ 6
#define __FLT_EPSILON__ 1.19209290e-7F
#define __FLT_EVAL_METHOD__ 0
#define __FLT_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __FLT_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __FLT_MANT_DIG__ 24
#define __FLT_MAX_10_EXP__ 38
#define __FLT_MAX_EXP__ 128
#define __FLT_MAX__ 3.40282347e+38F
#define __FLT_MIN_10_EXP__ (-37)
#define __FLT_MIN_EXP__ (-125)
#define __FLT_MIN__ 1.17549435e-38F
#define __FLT_RADIX__ 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_BOOL_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR16_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR32_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_LLONG_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_LONG_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_POINTER_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_SHORT_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_TEST_AND_SET_TRUEVAL 1
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GNUC_GNU_INLINE__ 1
#define __GNUC_MINOR__ 2
#define __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ 1
#define __GNUC__ 4
#define __GNUG__ 4
#define __GXX_ABI_VERSION 1002
#define __GXX_RTTI 1
#define __GXX_WEAK__ 1
#define __INT16_TYPE__ short
#define __INT32_TYPE__ int
#define __INT64_C_SUFFIX__ L
#define __INT64_TYPE__ long int
#define __INT8_TYPE__ char
#define __INTMAX_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __INTMAX_TYPE__ long int
#define __INTMAX_WIDTH__ 64
#define __INTPTR_TYPE__ long int
#define __INTPTR_WIDTH__ 64
#define __INT_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __LDBL_DENORM_MIN__ 4.94065645841246544176568792868221e-324L
#define __LDBL_DIG__ 31
#define __LDBL_EPSILON__ 4.94065645841246544176568792868221e-324L
#define __LDBL_HAS_DENORM__ 1
#define __LDBL_HAS_INFINITY__ 1
#define __LDBL_HAS_QUIET_NAN__ 1
#define __LDBL_MANT_DIG__ 106
#define __LDBL_MAX_10_EXP__ 308
#define __LDBL_MAX_EXP__ 1024
#define __LDBL_MAX__ 1.79769313486231580793728971405301e+308L
#define __LDBL_MIN_10_EXP__ (-291)
#define __LDBL_MIN_EXP__ (-968)
#define __LDBL_MIN__ 2.00416836000897277799610805135016e-292L
#define __LONG_DOUBLE_128__ 1
#define __LONG_LONG_MAX__ 9223372036854775807LL
#define __LONG_MAX__ 9223372036854775807L
#define __LP64__ 1
#define __MACH__ 1
#define __NATURAL_ALIGNMENT__ 1
#define __NO_INLINE__ 1
#define __ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__ 4321
#define __ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__ 1234
#define __ORDER_PDP_ENDIAN__ 3412
#define __PIC__ 2
#define __POINTER_WIDTH__ 64
#define __POWERPC__ 1
#define __PPC64__ 1
#define __PPC__ 1
#define __PRAGMA_REDEFINE_EXTNAME 1
#define __PTRDIFF_TYPE__ long int
#define __PTRDIFF_WIDTH__ 64
#define __REGISTER_PREFIX__
#define __SCHAR_MAX__ 127
#define __SHRT_MAX__ 32767
#define __SIG_ATOMIC_WIDTH__ 32
#define __SIZEOF_DOUBLE__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_FLOAT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_INT128__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_INT__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_DOUBLE__ 16
#define __SIZEOF_LONG_LONG__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_LONG__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_POINTER__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_PTRDIFF_T__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_SHORT__ 2
#define __SIZEOF_SIZE_T__ 8
#define __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ 4
#define __SIZEOF_WINT_T__ 4
#define __SIZE_MAX__ 18446744073709551615UL
#define __SIZE_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __SIZE_WIDTH__ 64
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
#define __STDC_UTF_16__ 1
#define __STDC_UTF_32__ 1
#define __STDC__ 1
#define __TARGETCONDITIONALS__
#define __UINTMAX_TYPE__ long unsigned int
#define __USER_LABEL_PREFIX__ _
#define __VERSION__ "4.2.1 Compatible Clang 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)"
#define __WCHAR_MAX__ 2147483647
#define __WCHAR_TYPE__ int
#define __WCHAR_WIDTH__ 32
#define __WINT_TYPE__ int
#define __WINT_WIDTH__ 32
#define __clang__ 1
#define __clang_major__ 3
#define __clang_minor__ 4
#define __clang_patchlevel__ 2
#define __clang_version__ "3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)"
#define __cplusplus 199711L
#define __llvm__ 1
#define __pic__ 2
#define __powerpc64__ 1
#define __powerpc__ 1
#define __ppc64__ 1
#define __ppc__ 1
#define __private_extern__ extern
#define __strong
#define __unsafe_unretained
#define __weak __attribute__((objc_gc(weak)))
```

Comment: Just looking into the header, the functions are available `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_2_0);`, therefore you will have to check for that system version, which also means checking for the given SDK versions during compilation. To be honest, it would be very rare to find someone actually using those OS_X/iOS version now.

Comment: Thanks @Sulthan. Go ahead an answer - OS X 10.7 and iOS 2.0 is the toehold we need. I also agree about the antique hardware. The only reason we jump through the hoops is for big-endian testing on the PowerPC cpu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look into the header, you will see that the functions are annotated `__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7, __IPHONE_2_0)`.

That means they are available since OS_X 10.7 and iOS 2.0.

You can check the specific macros during compilation.

Comment: Looks like there's also a `_SECURITY_SECRANDOM_H_` macro in the header, though checking for 10.7 should be fine.

Comment: @Wevah That's only the double include guard macro. You can only check it if you include the header. However, you cannot include the header if the header does not exist.

Comment: Oh, right, spaced that it was the include being (and having to be) wrapped.